# Install Eclipse IDE on UbuntuStudio

Tags: package-management, java, eclipse, netbeans, ubuntu-studio

I am considering a purchase where UbuntuStudio is pre-installed on a machine.  But, before I purchase the laptop, I am curious if packages such as Eclipse or Netbeans install on UbuntuStudio the same way that Eclipse would install on Ubuntu 20.04.  I realize that most people use UbuntuStudio because they are talented artists.  But, I have one young user that is artistic and another potential user that is more of a developer.  Could anyone help me out with this question before I mistakenly waste a thousand dollars?  (Thanks!)

Comment: All *official* Ubuntu flavors have the same base, the base found in Ubuntu itself, so the commands are the same with only the desktops varying (as each *flavor* has it's own desktop; that's what makes them a flavor).  Yes software installs identically via command, via package manager (though some come default with different package managers, as some are more efficient on some desktops, others on alternate desktops - but they all do the same thing).

Comment: @karel  Thank you.  Yes, that link does answer my question.  I did not find that thread on an earlier search.  The one thing that was tripping me up was that "Ubuntu Studio is optimized to reduce latency" for audio editing purposes.  So, with Linux drivers being such a pain, I was afraid that "Ubunu Studio" was not 100% interchangeable with "Ubuntu Vanilla".  Again, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

I can reassure you, I have been using Eclipse (currently Neon, various older versions before) on Ubuntu Studio 18.04 for a couple of years. I just tried it on my 20.04 laptop as well and it seems to run fine there too.

I recommend downloading the latest package from the Eclipse foundation website, and you can unpack and put it where you want. It is self-contained, no need for installation.

The only requirement is to have a proper Java JDK installed, but there are plenty of guides on how to do that.

That said, nothing prevents you from putting any other Ubuntu or Linux distribution on that PC either. But I personally prefer Ubuntu Studio in comparison to many other flavours, it is stable, efficient and overall nice to use. It's a good choice.